# Sequential numbering of IntegerField in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks more or less like that:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    period = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    beta = models.IntegerField()
    gamma = models.FloatField()
```

And I need `period` to be a number from 1 to N where N is number of records in this model. So if there are 5 records there it would be a set of integers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], but if someone deletes number 4, it should be updated in such a way that number 5 becomes 4, so they would be consecutive again.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Sequential numbering of your records is not something you would store in a database column. The 'right way to do it' depends on what exactly you want to do with that sequence of numbers. Maybe you could update your question with some information on that.

Comment: Some RDBMS provide a way to dynamically number the rows in your query, e.g. ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL and PostgreSQL, or the pseudocolumn `rownum` in Oracle.

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski why have you set it to `unique` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the .delete() and .save() methods to update the period number with the index position with regards to the entire queryset. The period value may not match the actual primary key of the instance but it will represent the cardinal position.

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def update_periods(self):
        for instance in self.all():
            instance.period = instance.get_index()
            instance.save()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    period = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    beta = models.IntegerField()
    gamma = models.FloatField()

    objects = MyModelManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)

    def get_index(self):
        # Return the index position of this instance with regards to the sorted queryset
        return list(MyModel.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)).index(self.pk) + 1

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        MyModel.objects.update_periods()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # Only update new instances
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            MyModel.objects.update_periods()
        else:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also use signal handlers to avoid overriding the model methods. This is a proof of concept. Updating all the periods this way is not efficient and would need to be updated to a bulk update using queryset annotations or a database function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/).

Comment: "You can also use signal handlers to avoid overriding the model methods." => signal handlers are for when you don't have the hand on the model. Using them for ie post-save processing _on your own models_ is an antipattern.